# Convert 3:00 PM Eastern Time(Us & Canada) to UTC taking into account daylight saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timezone

I need to find the records between 3:00 PM yesterday and 3:00 PM today in the user's time zone. The user's time zone is Eastern Time(Us & Canada) taking daylight saving into consideration. How can I get the records? (Also my server's time is in UTC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Time.zone = "Eastern Time (US & Canada)"
Time.zone.parse(params[:start_date]).utc
```

NB: To see valid US time zones you can run `rake time:zones:us`

Comment: Thanks man..I have already configured config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)' in the `environment.rb` file. So, I needed to do just `Time.zone.parse(Date.today.to_s + "3:00 PM").utc`. Also, the rake task is `rake time:zones:us`